# How to catch 'bigint out of range' error in a view?

Tags: postgresql, outofrangeexception

I have a table with three columns, `length`, `width` and `height`, all `integer`s and constraint to not become larger than `1000000`.

When calculating volume, I cast to `bigint` and it all fits. However, I have a view that multiplies the volume by another value and that can result in a

> ERROR:  bigint out of range

for those records that actually have the maximum volume and are multiplied by anything larger than 9.

Is there a way to catch that (e.g. return `NULL` instead when overflowing) instead of bailing out with an error and not returning anything?

Comment: Would it be possible to use numeric instead of bigint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would cast the value to `numeric` before doing the calculation, which would avoid the error.

If you need to have the result as a `bigint`, you could use a construct like this:

```
WITH num_results AS (
   SELECT CAST(value AS numeric) * ... AS bigresult
   FROM ...
)
SELECT CASE WHEN bigresult BETWEEN -9223372036854775808 AND 9223372036854775807
            THEN CAST(bigresult AS bigint)
            ELSE NULL
       END, ...
FROM num_results;
```